# org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Database relates to a more recent version of sonar

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube-4.5

I am facing the below error.

org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings.

i have 2 different servers. one for sonar and another for database.
1. I have taken snapshot of sonar server, but i didnot take snapshot for database(forgot to take it).
2. I have upgraded sonar from sonar 4.0 to sonarqube4.5.1 after taking backup of database(postgresql) using pg_dump command... but as i have faced some loss of data after upgrading sonar and database i have reverted back to previous snapshot (sonar server)
3. now we have done restoring the database using pg_restore command successfully but the sonar 4.0 is not getting started and gives the above error

could anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Message is quite obvious. You are starting your SQ 4.0 instance connected to a DB which is recognized as more recent.

Options are limited:

- either the DB is really your original SQ 4.0 DB and you are not running the exact same SQ 4.0 software you used to
- or you are running the same SQ 4.0 software and the DB is not your original SQ 4.0 DB

My guess is that you did not successfully restore your DB to its SQ 4.0 state, or only partially.

Under the hood, SQ uses table `schema_migrations` to know which version of the DB it is connected to.

Each db migration "script" (lets use that name for simplicity sake) has a unique number (number is strictly increasing) and each SQ version knows the number of the last migration script it bundles. When a script is successfully executed, a row is added to table `schema_migrations`.

SQ checks at startup its last script's number against the highest number in `schema_migrations`:

- same number, everything is ok
- lower number, DB needs an upgrade
- higher number, the error message you got